# Closing a file after File.Create

Tags: c#, file-io

I check to see if a file exists with

```
if(!File.Exists(myPath))
{
    File.Create(myPath);
}
```

However, when I go to create a `StreamReader` with this newly created file, I get an error saying that

> The process cannot access the file '[my file path here]' because it is being used by another process.

There isn't a `File.Close(myPath)` that I can call so that it is closed after being created, so how do I free this resource so that I can open it later in my program?

Comment: Use it like this `File.Create(myPath).Close();`.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

[`File.Create(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) returns an instance of the [`FileStream` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx). You can call the [`Stream.Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx) method on this object in order to close it and release resources that it's using:

```
var myFile = File.Create(myPath);
myFile.Close();
```

However, since `FileStream` implements [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), you can take advantage of the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) (generally the preferred way of handling a situation like this). This will ensure that the stream is closed and disposed of properly when you're done with it:

```
using (var myFile = File.Create(myPath))
{
   // interact with myFile here, it will be disposed automatically
}
```

Comment: I only want to create the file and then immediately close it, without doing anything else. Would it still make sense to use using() ?

Answer (score 60):

The function returns a `FileStream` object. So you could use it's return value to open your `StreamWriter` or close it using the proper method of the object:

```
File.Create(myPath).Close();
```

Comment: And what happen, if your path is wrong and make an error, never close File. and then you were in troubles, or I am wrong?.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla if his path is wrong no file will be created and no stream will be open.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is because a FileStream is returned from your method to create a file. You should return the FileStream into a variable or call the close method directly from it after the File.Create.

It is a best practice to let the using block help you implement the IDispose pattern for a task like this. Perhaps what might work better would be:

```
if(!File.Exists(myPath)){
   using(FileStream fs = File.Create(myPath))
   using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs)){
      // do your work here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`File.Create` returns a `FileStream` object that you can call `Close()` on.

Answer (score 5):

```
File.WriteAllText(file,content)
```

create
write
close

```
File.WriteAllBytes--   type binary
```

:)

Comment: Excellent and Fashion solution my friend. Get out my 5 lines of code by one... thank you