# Error : The operation has timed out

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

I am trying to save an Excel file to a share location.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string conn =      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameConn"].ConnectionString;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection odbcCon = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                odbcCon.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetValues", odbcCon);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "abc");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dt);

            }
    string destFilename = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/A.xls");
    System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    client.DownloadFile(path, destFilename);
}

Web.config

<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="10000" maxRequestLength="2147483647" shutdownTimeout="360" />
```

And I get this error:

> - The operation has timed out.

Can you tell me where I could be wrong.

Comment: is the file currently open in Excel?

Comment: @D.Mac I am making the file and storing it. i think **var destFilename = File.Create(@"\\Networkserver path\websites");** would convert to a string to store the dest file.

Comment: @Bolu "path" will contain the downloaded data where as destFilename will  receive the data. But I get error in the line **var destFilename = File.Create(@"\\Networkserver path\websites");**

Comment: oh okay, it's just I often get this error when using C# to parse Excel docs and the actual document is left open.  Could be a similar issue here, that it is being created but it's open. I wonder if this would help? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156254/closing-a-file-after-file-create

Comment: you don't need to create a file to save the downloaded data, the WebClient.DownloadFile Method will do that for you, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[`File.Create` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx), while [`WebClient.DownloadFile` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx) needs two `string` parameters one for `The URI from which to download data.` and the other for `The name of the local file that is to receive the data.`

So you should do something like:

```
//you may also need to check if the file is exist. 
string destFilename = @"\\Networkserver path\websites\destexcel.xlsx";

System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(path, destFilename);
```

Comment: If I do this: 
`string destFilename = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/abc.xls");
                    System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
                    client.DownloadFile(path, destFilename);`

**path is a web service call which will get the data**
It works fine, But  instead of storing on a local system, I want to store it on a network path.

Comment: @hello, can't you setup a virtual directory in your IIS and maps it to your shared network path, then use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path/abc.xls)` in the `DownloadFile` method?

Comment: I get Time out Error. I have a database connectivity , so would there be a timeout for my sql connection or my application ?

Comment: @hello, based on your code, it will most possibly be a WebException timeout. Can you update your code?

Comment: @hello, just want to clarify: have you resolved the previous error? and this is a new error you are facing?

Comment: I do not know whther the previous error has been solved or not. I tried to change the code s you mentioned and then started facing this issue.

Comment: @hello, set breakpoints, and use debug, when you find your exact error and its related line of code, update it in your question.

Comment: @hello, then, in your first comments above, did you say it works fine if you use local path like `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/abc.xls")` ? If that is not what you mean, please post your `path` in your function `client.DownloadFile(path, destFilename);` as I can't guess what it is....