# Creating a Txt-File and write to it

Tags: c#, textbox, text-files

I want to create a text file then add the text of a `TextBox` to it.
Creating the text file works without any problems with following code:

```
InitializeComponent();
string path = @"C:\Users\Morris\Desktop\test.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Create(path);
}
```

But I get an error that the file is being used when I try to add the text to the text file. If the file already exist before it run the code I don't get this error and the `TextBox.Text` is added to the File.
I use this code to add the text to the text file:

```
public void writeTxt()
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\Morris\Desktop\test.txt";
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            tw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text);
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Try changing `File.Create(path);` to `using (File.Create(path));`

Comment: Thank you, it works pefect now ;)
I did not see the other question, sorry for asking a similar question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't actually have to check if the file exists, as StreamWriter will do that for you.

```
using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
{
    tw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text);
}
```

> public StreamWriter(
>            string path,
>            bool append
>        )
>
> Determines whether data is to be appended to the file. If the file exists and append is false, the file is overwritten. If the file exists and append is true, the data is appended to the file. Otherwise, a new file is created.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. I'm changing my code from the ground up so there is still a lot of irrelevant code to be removed. But I did not know that StreamWriter will check it for me.

Comment: yes, `Otherwise, a new file is created.`

Comment: Perfect I had the StramWritter in place but I wasn't sure it will create or writte if there is already there, seems I didn't need to control that! nice and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use [File.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) with `using` statement as it's locking the file on creating.So just change this line :

```
File.Create(path);
```

To this:

```
using (File.Create(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file exists, it can be either overwritten or appended to. If the file does not exist, this constructor creates a new file. So you don't need to check if the file exists or not.

You need to make sure the file is closed before you want to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here, `StreamWriter`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,6ea2d7950726035c,references) will actually create a file on specified path when it doesn't exist so it's useless to check for it.

I would suggest to remove the part which is creating the file and simply just start writing :

```
public void writeTxt()
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\Morris\Desktop\test.txt";
    using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    {
        tw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text);
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

---

But if you really want to create the file beforehand, remember to [`Dispose`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,f922405b11eca536,references) `FileStream` object created by `File.Create` call. [`Dispose`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,f922405b11eca536,references) call will automatically call `Flush` and `Close` for you so it's safe enough and you can do this in many ways like this :

```
InitializeComponent();
string path = @"C:\Users\Morris\Desktop\test.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    using ( File.Create(path) ) ; // This will generate warnings that you're not using the object and so on, but that's okay,
}
```

Or like this :

```
InitializeComponent();
string path = @"C:\Users\Morris\Desktop\test.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
    fs.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to Move your

```
tw.Close();
```

Outside your using. Like so :

```
public void writeTxt()
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\Morris\Desktop\test.txt";
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            tw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text);
        }
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

Edit : As pointed out, when the using ends the writer is disposed, so does not need manually closing.

```
public void writeTxt()
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\Morris\Desktop\test.txt";
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            tw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `tw` is disposed by the time it reaches `Close`...

Comment: `using` is closing `tw` when it exits the scope

Comment: Of corse! Thanks for pointing that out. in that case no need to do .close at all.

Answer (score -2):

This problem has been answered before in this thread. 
[Closing a file after File.Create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156254/closing-a-file-after-file-create)

You will need to close the stream to the file before using it again.

Comment: That's why you should flag the question as a duplicate.