# Creating a file and writing in it using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a file and write in it using C# code below:

```cs
string machinename;

// CHECKING IF THE DIRECTORY EXISTS OR NOT -- IF NOT CREATE ONE
if (!Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Settings\")) 
 Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath + @"\Settings\");

// CHECKING IF THE FILE EXISTS OR NOT -- IF NOT CREATE ONE
if (!File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Settings\info.txt"))
 File.CreateText(Application.StartupPath + @"\Settings\info.txt");

// READING THE CONTNET OF THE FILE AND WRITING IT IN A STRING 
machinename = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + @"\Settings\info.txt");

// IF THE CONTENT IS EMPTY THEN WRITE IN THE FILE FOR FURTHUR USE
if (machinename == "")
{
   File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + @"\Settings\info.txt", Environment.MachineName);
   machinename = Environment.MachineName;
}

// Do Stuff with "machinename"
```

But I get the following error :

> Message = The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

And it throws the exception on this line :

```cs
machinename = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + @"\Settings\info.txt");
```

Exactly after creating the file.

(This means if the exists **but** it is empty it can read it and write in it, But it cant create and read from it).

That is because functions `ReadAllText` and `WriteAllText` use the embedded `File.Close()` and by what I see `File.CreateText()` does not have it.

**Now the question is:**

How can I makes sure that the process `Closes` the file after creating it?

**NOTES:**

> 1. No I am not using the file in other places of the code.
> 2. I have read other answers about this particular kind of error in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741191/ioexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-file-path-because-it-is-being)
>    but it does not answer my question
> 3. The link above mostly uses `StreamWriter` which I don not want to use because my string is not a large one to process and it is easier to use this way.

Comment: You need to close the StreamWriter. That's done for you if you use a `using` block, or you can call `Close()` manually.

Comment: @TiesonT. I am not using the streamWriter. and on the other hand ```File``` does not have a ```Close()``` property

Comment: Yeah, you are: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createtext?view=net-5.0 - StreamWriter is what's returned by `File.CreateText()`.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156254/closing-a-file-after-file-create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation `public static System.IO.StreamWriter CreateText (string path);` (a `StreamWriter` is returned) and so on (reading documentation) ... a `StreamWriter` is a (inherits from) `TextWriter` which is `IDisposable`, so you should be doing this...

```
if (!File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Settings\info.txt"))
{
    var sw = File.CreateText(Application.StartupPath + @"\Settings\info.txt");
    sw.Dispose();
}
```

or better yet

```
if (!File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Settings\info.txt"))
    using (var sw = File.CreateText(Application.StartupPath + @"\Settings\info.txt"))
    {/* do nothing, but end of using does the Dispose() for you */}
```

or best of all

```
if (!File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Settings\info.txt"))
    File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + @"\Settings\info.txt",
```

because `WriteAlltext()` doesn't need the file to exist before it is called.

(Or you could use that `StreamWriter` to write the machine name...)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `File.CreateText` you don't have to create the text before calling `File.WriteAllText`, it will create the file if it doesn't exist. just try to delete `File.Createtext`

Use the code below:

```cs
if (!File.Exists(mypath))
    File.WriteAllText(mypath, myString);
else
    mynewString = File.ReadAllText(mypath);
```

Comment: One reason that I am checking the existence of the file is because I don't want the application to always write in file... Simply I want to say if it is there... skip the writing part and read from it. But it works fine

Comment: i understand what you say , but you could just check  for existence and don't create File
, is it clear to You what is my purpose ? i want you to remove CreateText from your Code , and your Code Will Work Fine Without Any exception.

Comment: Yeap I just did that and I checked it and I write in it 
no creation needed