# .NET MAUI access denied to AppData folder on Android

Tags: c#, android, maui

I've been trying to access the AppData folder on Android.

I've written the following `PermissionsHelper` class

```cs
public static class PermissionsHelper
{
    public static async void RequestRequiredPermissions()
    {
        PermissionStatus statusRead = await RequestPermission<Permissions.StorageRead>();
        PermissionStatus statusWrite = await RequestPermission<Permissions.StorageWrite>();

        // ...
    }

    public static async Task<PermissionStatus> RequestPermission<T>(string? explanation = null) where T: Permissions.BasePermission, new()
    {
        PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<T>();

        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();

            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted && explanation != null)
            {
                if (Application.Current != null && Application.Current.MainPage != null)
                {
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Please Grant Permission", explanation, "OK");
                }
            }
        }

        return status;
    }
}
```

Now in the below code, I'm trying to access the AppData directory to write the JSON form of an object to a file:

```cs
public async void WriteObjectToJsonFile(string filepath, object? obj)
{
    if (await PermissionsHelper.RequestPermission<Permissions.StorageWrite>() != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        return;

    string json = ObjectToJson(obj);

    string folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath) ?? "";

    if (!File.Exists(filepath))
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

        var x = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>(); // for testing
        File.Create(filepath).Close();
    }

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filepath))
    {
        sw.Write(json);
    }
}
```

Now when I call this function:

```cs
localDataService.WriteObjectToJsonFile(
    AppLocalDirectories.AppDataDirectory, // FileSystem.AppDataDirectory
    BaseSchedule);
```

..on Windows, this code works perfectly fine. On Android, however, I get the following exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path >'/data/user/0/com.company.appname/files' is denied.'

I've checked in my app's settings if the storage permission has been granted or not (it has). I've also added the following to my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What can be a possible solution? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you request about permissions like the line of code : status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>(); it shows a dialog about the specific permission and you accept it right?

Comment: @NikosBasdanis yes. And as mentioned, I've also checked in my app settings on my android, and the permission is granted there as well.

Comment: Could you please provide a repo to dig deeper ?

Comment: Does the `/files` subdirectory exist? If not, that may explain the exception you see. AFAIK, you shouldn't need any extra permissions to read and write files that are located in your app's private data folder on Android, see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage for more info. Make sure to use `FileSystem.AppDataDirectory` to access the correct path. You may need to create subdirectories first before writing files. Anyway, those permissions you are requesting are for external storage, e.g. memory cards and shareable media.

Comment: @Julian thanks for the response! I've already checked my android, the `/files` subdirectory does exist. I'm also checking that through code: `if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);`

Comment: This line looks suspicious: `File.Create(filepath).Close();` Why do you close the file right away and then attempt to write to it using the `StreamWriter` just a few lines later? You could instead create the file with a using statement: `using (var file = File.Create(filepath)) { /* write to file here */ }` and then write to the file within the code block, which then disposes the file stream automatically once you're done, e.g. like is done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5156334/4308455

Comment: @Julian I tried what you suggested with no success. The problem is that I have no access to `/data/user/0/.../files` due to some reason.

Comment: Remove all the permissions code. Write what android version you are using, and what device. Show me where and how you are calling this code "FileSystem.AppDataDirectory". Those async voids are terrible too.

Comment: Although I agree about the bad practice of using `async void` instead of awaitable `async Task`, this shouldn't be causing the `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Comment: @Julian he is getting this error, because he is trying to use a folder like a file. I am trying to teach him to fix his other problems. I could say "add 1.txt after it and it will work", and all this mess would never get fixed.

Comment: @H.A.H. thanks for your reply! I'm relatively new to C# async programming, I apologize for my mistakes. I had my exams going, so I forgot about this question for a while. I managed to fix my problems earlier, and it was exactly what you say! I isolated the code into another project and debugged it to find that I was indeed using the folder as a file by mistake. That, and also some issue with the built assemblies. I had to clean the project. Also, I have improved my async programming skills since then, so I'll make sure not to use `async void` without reason. Thanks for your help and time!